# Boundedness of $\chi_{\{f_n=0\}}$ in the BV norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sequences-and-series, sobolev-spaces

Let $f_n \in H^2(\Omega) \cap C^0(\bar \Omega)$ be a sequence of functions that are uniformly bounded in $H^2(\Omega) \cap C^0(\bar \Omega)$ on a smooth bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \leq 3$.

I want to know whether the characteristic functions of the zero level sets 
$$\chi_{\{f_n=0\}}(x) = \begin{cases}
1 : f_n(x)=0\\
0 : f_n(x) \neq 0
\end{cases}$$ 
are such that $\chi_{\{f_n=0\}}$ is bounded uniformly in $n$ in the [BV space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#Formal_definition).

---

Clearly the problem is in showing that the BV seminorm is bounded. I tried using the coarea formula to rewrite the seminorm in terms of the perimeters of the level sets associated to the function $\chi_{\{f_n=0\}}$, and the problem reduces (unless I made a mistake) to showing that
$$\sup_{\phi \in C_c^1(\Omega)^n, |\phi| \leq 1}\int_{\{f_n=0\}} \nabla \cdot \phi$$
is uniformly bounded in $n$, but I was unable to proceed further.

---

I also additionally know that $f_n \geq 0$ a.e. and $\chi_{\{f_n =0 \}}$ converges weak-* to some element in $L^\infty(\Omega)$ (not necessarily another characteristic function).

Comment: Given that you can construct a $C^\infty$ function whose $0$ set is any prescribed closed set and that characteristic functions of closed sets are definitely not all in BV, the answer should be "No".